# Multiuser server handling disconnections

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I'm trying to create a multi user/client UDP server which is sending out an audio stream to whoever connects to the server.

It is working great so far but If I kill one of the clients it throws an error in EndReceiveFrom when the client is closed which then means that I never call BeginReceiveFrom again. If I try and call BeginReceiveFrom again it will throw a SocketException 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'

This is my server code (excluding the Send function).

```
    public UdpServer(IPAddress ipAddress, int port)
    {
        _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp)
        {
            ExclusiveAddressUse = false
        };

        _socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port));

        StartListening();
    }

    private void StartListening(EndPoint epSender = null)
    {
        if (epSender == null)
            epSender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

        _socket.BeginReceiveFrom(ByteData, 0, ByteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epSender, OnReceive, epSender);
    }

    private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        var sender = (EndPoint)ar.AsyncState;

        try
        {
            var clients = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            var epSender = (EndPoint)clients;

            _socket.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref epSender);

            if(!_clients.Any(c => c.Equals(epSender)))
                _clients.Add(epSender);

            StartListening(epSender);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _clients.Remove(sender);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

My Client is pretty basic. I send a message of 'hello' just so the server knows the client exists

```
var udp = new UdpClient();
var ipEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), 9009);
udp.Connect(ipEp);

var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello");
udp.Send(bytes, bytes.Length);

udp.BeginReceive(OnBeginReceive, new object());
```

Comment: The problem description doesn't make much sense. UDP is a connectionless protocol. You can't really connect a socket (all that calling `Connect()` on a UDP socket does is restrict datagrams received to the "connected" end-point), and UDP has no way to know that the remote end-point it was hoping to hear from has been closed, never mind cause the hopeful recipient to detect a reset connection. In other words, if you're actually getting the behavior you say you are, there's something weird going on, in the part of the code you didn't post. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Have you ever been able to fix this? I'm having the same problem, i'm finding it strage i'm getting this error since UDP is supposed to be connection less (on network level it's a ICMP message that is being send from the remote (closed) port which causes this error)